# How do I keep MDScrollView from truncating my row headers and making my cells look bad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

Here's a screenshot to show what I am describing: [image: screenshot]

And the relevant code:

```
 - (NSInteger)spreadView:(MDSpreadView *)aSpreadView numberOfColumnsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
  return self.viewModel.matrix.width - 1;
}

- (NSInteger)spreadView:(MDSpreadView *)aSpreadView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
  return self.viewModel.matrix.height - 1;
}

-(MDSpreadViewCell *)spreadView:(MDSpreadView *)aSpreadView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(MDIndexPath *)rowPath forColumnAtIndexPath:(MDIndexPath *)columnPath{
  MDSpreadViewCell *cell = [aSpreadView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"InfoCell"];

  if (cell == nil){
    cell = [[[MDSpreadViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:MDSpreadViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"InfoCell"] autorelease];
  }

  cell.textLabel.text = ((DTVendor *)self.vendors[rowPath.row]).name;

  return cell;
}

-(CGFloat)spreadView:(MDSpreadView *)aSpreadView heightForRowHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)rowSection{
  return 200;
}

-(CGFloat)spreadView:(MDSpreadView *)aSpreadView widthForColumnHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)columnSection{
  return 200;
}

-(CGFloat)spreadView:(MDSpreadView *)aSpreadView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(MDIndexPath *)indexPath{
  return 200;
}

-(CGFloat)spreadView:(MDSpreadView *)aSpreadView widthForColumnAtIndexPath:(MDIndexPath *)indexPath{
  return 200;
}

-(id)spreadView:(MDSpreadView *)aSpreadView titleForHeaderInColumnSection:(NSInteger)section forRowAtIndexPath:(MDIndexPath *)rowPath{
  return ((DTVendor *)self.vendors[rowPath.row]).name;
}

-(id)spreadView:(MDSpreadView *)aSpreadView titleForHeaderInRowSection:(NSInteger)section forColumnAtIndexPath:(MDIndexPath *)columnPath{
  return ((DTVendor *)self.vehicleClasses[columnPath.column]).name;
}
```

MDScrollView is truncating column header labels and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you would return a size of the longest header text instead of fixed size, you could keep the size of longest header and keep updating it if headers text is edited.